# Find the row echelon form of a 4x4 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to row reduce the following matrix into an echelon form:
\begin{pmatrix}
-(-\beta+\alpha)^{1/2} & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
 0&  -(-\beta+\alpha)^{1/2}& 0 & 1\\ 
-\beta & \alpha &  -(-\beta+\alpha)^{1/2}&0 \\ 
\alpha & -\beta & 0 & -(-\beta+\alpha)^{1/2}
\end{pmatrix}

where $\beta = k(1/M + 1/m)$, $\alpha = k/m$

I have no idea. I have been sitting here in the library for two hours doing calculations like $-\beta + \alpha = -k/M$, trying to add rows together, having the $-(-\beta+\alpha)^{1/2} = -i\sqrt{k/M}$, letting $-(-\beta+\alpha)^{1/2} = \gamma$ and I just don't know anymore

Comment: What do you mean by solving the matrix? Do you want to find the determinant of the matrix?

Comment: What does "solve" mean? There is no equation here...row-reduce? Find the determinant? Find eigenvalues?

Comment: Echo Paul and afedder. And it should be $-(-\beta + \alpha)^{1/2} = -i\sqrt{k/M}$.

Comment: Sorry guys long night

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the rows $(1)$ through $(4)$. I will explicitly tell you the steps to produce row-reduced echelon form, assuming $\alpha \neq \beta$ and $\alpha \neq 0.$ $$$$
**Step 1**: Add $-\beta(\alpha - \beta)^{-1/2} \times (1)$ to $(3)$.

**Step 2**: Add $\alpha(\alpha - \beta)^{-1/2} \times (1)$ to $(4)$.

**Step 3**: Subtract $(2)$ from $(3)$.

**Step 4**: Add $-\beta \times (2)$ to $(4)$.

**Step 5**: Divide $(4)$ by $\alpha$.

**Step 6**: Subtract $(3)$ from $(4)$.

**Step 7**: Subtract $(3)$ from $(1)$.

**Step 8**: Divide $(2)$ by $-(\alpha - \beta)^{1/2}$.

**Step 9**: Divide $(1)$ by $-(\alpha - \beta)^{1/2}$.

This will produce the following matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & -(\alpha - \beta)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -(\alpha - \beta)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: How did you see that this was the solution?

Comment: @DonLarynx The steps are clear, right? You just eliminate one entry at a time...

Comment: Just worked it out...honestly first thing I did was try to get rid of $\alpha$ and $-\beta$ in $(3)$ and $(4)$. It wasn't too difficult once I did this. @DonLarynx

Comment: I tried that yesterday, maybe I just suck at math. I am doing the steps right now, will report back if I have a question.

Comment: My suggestion is to look at what you can eliminate one row at a time until you have something manageable, where you can see the rest of the row-reduction easily. @DonLarynx

Comment: Why would I need to subtract row 3 from row 1?

Comment: In order to eliminate the $1$ in the *entry* $(1,3)$ such that the pair $(i,j)$ is the $i$-th row, $j$-th column *entry*. @DonLarynx ...name this matrix $A$, then notice $\text{rank}(A)$.

Answer (score 3):

Set $\gamma=-(-\beta+\alpha)^{1/2}$; then your matrix becomes
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
 0&  \gamma & 0 & 1\\ 
-\beta & \alpha &  \gamma &0 \\ 
\alpha & -\beta & 0 & \gamma
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, multiply the first row by $\gamma^{-1}$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \gamma^{-1} & 0\\ 
 0&  \gamma & 0 & 1\\ 
-\beta & \alpha &  \gamma &0 \\ 
\alpha & -\beta & 0 & \gamma
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Add to the third row the first multiplied by $\beta$; then add to the fourth row the first multiplied by $-\alpha$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \gamma^{-1} & 0\\ 
 0&  \gamma & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & \alpha &  \gamma+\beta\gamma^{-1} &0 \\ 
0 & -\beta & -\alpha\gamma^{-1} & \gamma
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Multiply the second row by $\gamma^{-1}$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \gamma^{-1} & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & \gamma^{-1}\\ 
0 & \alpha &  \gamma+\beta\gamma^{-1} &0 \\ 
0 & -\beta & -\alpha\gamma^{-1} & \gamma
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Add to the third row the second row multiplied by $-\alpha$; add to the fourth row the second row multiplied by $\beta$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \gamma^{-1} & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & \gamma^{-1}\\ 
0 & 0 &  \gamma+\beta\gamma^{-1} &-\alpha\gamma^{-1} \\ 
0 & 0 & -\alpha\gamma^{-1} & \gamma+\beta\gamma^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now observe that
$$
\gamma+\beta\gamma^{-1}=\frac{\gamma^2+\beta}{\gamma}=\alpha\gamma^{-1}
$$
Thus the matrix you got is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \gamma^{-1} & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & \gamma^{-1}\\ 
0 & 0 &  \alpha\gamma^{-1} &-\alpha\gamma^{-1} \\ 
0 & 0 & -\alpha\gamma^{-1} & \alpha\gamma^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Multiply the third row by $\alpha^{-1}\gamma$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \gamma^{-1} & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & \gamma^{-1}\\ 
0 & 0 &  1 & -1 \\ 
0 & 0 & -\alpha\gamma^{-1} & \alpha\gamma^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Finally, add to the fourth row the third row multiplied by $\alpha\gamma^{-1}$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \gamma^{-1} & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & \gamma^{-1}\\ 
0 & 0 &  1 & -1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The reduced row echelon form is obtained now by adding to the first row the third row multiplied by $-\gamma^{-1}$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma^{-1}\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & \gamma^{-1}\\ 
0 & 0 &  1 & -1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Of course, this assumes that $\gamma\ne0$ (that is $\alpha\ne\beta$) and $\alpha\ne0$. Depending on your assumptions, these cases should be examined separately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 &  &  & \\
0 & 1 &  & \\
0 & \sqrt{\alpha-\beta} & -\sqrt{\alpha-\beta} & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha-\beta}}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1\\
0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & \frac{\beta}{\alpha}\\
0 & 0 & -\frac{\beta}{\alpha} & \frac{\alpha}{\beta}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1\\
0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & -\frac{\sqrt{\alpha-\beta}}{\beta}\\
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{\alpha-\beta}}{\alpha}
\end{array}\right]\\\cdot\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
-\sqrt{-\beta+\alpha} & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -\sqrt{-\beta+\alpha} & 0 & 1\\
-\beta & \alpha & -\sqrt{-\beta+\alpha} & 0\\
\alpha & -\beta & 0 & -\sqrt{-\beta+\alpha}
\end{array}\right]=$$

$$=-\sqrt{\alpha-\beta}\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha-\beta}} & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha-\beta}}\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: I dont quite follow this

Comment: The end result is a row reduced matrix. The pre-multiply matrices represent the steps needed to get there. So if you pre-multiply the right hand side (which is missing from the post) with the same matrices you will end up with a row reduced system of equation.